# Python set assistance

Tags: python, set

So I'm trying to make a recommendation system but with sets and text files.
I currently have:

```
colours=["black","yellow","pink","gold","light red",
"turquoise","olive","orchid","brown","orange",
"purple","golden","light blue","sandy brown","spring green",
"maroon","gray","red","green","cyan","chocolate","salmon"]

user_rec=set()

for x in range (3):
  user=input(str(x+1)+". Enter the numbers of your 3 favourite colours:\n> ")
  print()
  user_rec.add(user)
print(user_rec)

with open("Colours.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        fields=line.split(' ')
        colour1=int(fields[0])
        colour2=int(fields[1])
        colour3=int(fields[2])
        set(line).add(colour1)
        set(line).add(colour2)
        set(line).add(colour3)
        print(set(line))
```

where Colours is the text file that contains 100 lines of 3 randomly generated numbers which represent the colours in the array.

The first line of the line is "8 9 17" but I get the output "{' ','7','1','9','8','\n'}" when I just want {8,9,17} so I can compare each line set to the user's set to recommend them another colour using intersection.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're printing `set(line)`. You're not using `fields` or `colour1` at all…

Comment: Since you are not assigning `set(line)` to a variable, things like `set(line).add(colour1)` are creating sets which are promptly lost forever. The last 4 lines of your loop can probably be replaced by `print({colour1,colour2,colour3})`. Just create the set you want directly. There is no point in building it item by item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set(line)` constructs a set of all **characters** in the line, and that's what you print. What you want to do is:

```
with open("Colours.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        fields=line.strip().split() # you want to remove \n
        s = {int(item) for item in fields}
        print(s)
```